# Place a image view and a Text view in same line

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have several logos and i want to set a Textview right next to it so that they are in the same line. I can't place them in the same line.please help me. I want my textview right next to my image.

my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!--
      <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_contactdetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_contactdet"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:toRightof="@+id/pointer"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_address"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pointer"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"

        android:src="@drawable/pointer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_telephone1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_tp1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
          android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/telephone"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/call" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_telephone2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_tp2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
          android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fax"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fax" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_email"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
         android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_facility"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_facility"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fac1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fac1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fac3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fac3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fac2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fac2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change  android:orientation="horizontal"

Comment: Put them in their own nested LinearLayouts just like the ImageViews at the bottom. Also, you probably want the heights for those layouts to be `wrap_content`.

Comment: should i use separate linear layouts or can i use only one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1**:

Like others have suggested, you can have a nested `LinearLayout`with horizontal orientation. It will contain both `TextView` and `ImageView` with weights set according to your need.

See [How to set ImageView and the textView in a single line inside a LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298136/how-to-set-imageview-and-the-textview-in-a-single-line-inside-a-linearlayout)

Eg:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         ...
         />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:text="Test2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Method 2 [ Easier ]**:

Since you mentioned that you've several logos and want to set the drawable/ImageView right next to it, there is an easier alternate way. Supposing you want something like this:
[image]

You can use [android:drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft) or similar in the `TextView`. You can also set the padding between the drawable and the text of the TextView using [android:drawablePadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawablePadding). Using this way you don't need the extra ImageView. But it depends at the end what you are looking for.

See [Programmatically set left drawable in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931900/setting-drawableleft-in-a-textview-problem)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableRow as well. Here you don't need to specify the **android:orientation="horizontal"**.

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for all the views in Relative Layout to make them in a single vertical line.

```
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     />

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:text="Test2"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```